# Why is Hugo serving blank pages?

Tags: hugo

I am building a personal website using Hugo Static Page Generator, but when I do `hugo serve`, I am no longer seeing a page, but simply a blank page at `localhost:1313`.

I deleted everything and did a fresh install. But still, Hugo is serving blank pages.

In the blank page, I see the Favicon of the previous site draft I had, even though I deleted everything from the previous theme. I cleared the browser in Chrome and tried a different browser too, but it's still not working.

Not sure what information I can provide, as there are no error messages. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you set the theme in your `config.toml` file? Is the theme name in your `config.toml` the same has the folder name you have in the `themes/` folder? It might help if you post the contents of your `config.toml` file here.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was all about the template

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is likely to be the [theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/) - it is either missing or broken. Hugo does not come with any default/fallback theme if you fail to provide a working one.

Debugging guide:

1. Check the `themes` folder, and follow the [quickstart](https://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/).
2. Try using another, simpler theme.
3. It may only be a question of configuring the theme, you may read the [hugo theme documentation](https://gohugo.io/themes/) too.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like the cause. @maximumdooku What theme are you using? It probably needs fixing on GitHub, so if you let us know then someone can fix it for you.

Answer (score 10):

Please verify your config.toml file points to right theme.

If following Quick start tutorial, you might have forgot to run

```
echo 'theme = "ananke"' >> config.toml
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue after following the  [hugo getting-started / quickstart](https://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/) guide but instead of using an existing theme i created a very basic theme:

1. [Install hugo](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing) i picked [install hugo on windows](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing#windows)
2. Create a New Site `hugo new site quickstart`
3. Add a Theme

   - cloning a theme (for example the [ananke-theme](https://github.com/budparr/gohugo-theme-ananke) ) is easier  `<-- this is what the quickstart does and what i left out`
   - instead you can [create a theme](https://gohugo.io/themes/creating/)  with `hugo new theme [your-theme-name]` which adds a theme skeleton inside your site-folder  for example `C:\Hugo\Sites\example.com` (see the screenshot)
4. Add Some Content `hugo new posts/my-first-post.md`
5. Start the server `hugo server -D --watch --verbose`

[image: Hugo_myFirstTheme_files_folders]

After you created a theme files and folders should be under `Sites/example.com/themes/your-theme-name/`. Since most of the generated files are (nearly) empty you have to edit a few of them before the quickstart sample is working.

Based on [develop a Theme for Hugo](https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/develop-a-theme-for-hugo)  i edited `/themes/your-theme-name/layouts/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <body>    
    {{ range first 10 .Data.Pages }}        
         <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
         <div>{{- .Content -}}</div>
    {{ end }}      
</body> </html>
```

#### Basic information about hugo taken from [develop a Theme for Hugo](https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/develop-a-theme-for-hugo)

- Hugo configuration files (TOML, YAML or JSON) are located in the root of your site
- Hugo default: Markdown inside `content/`,

  - content files contain metadata ([frontmatter](https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#readout)) and text (/markdown) --> html to public/,
  - example frontmatter attributes: `date, title, description, categories, tags`
- templates under `themes/` (or `layouts/`)

  - three types of templates: `single, list, partials`
  - theme templates under `/themes/your-theme-name/` and then under `/layouts/` for `index.html` and under `/layouts/_default/list.html` and `/layouts/_default/single.html`
- HTML files will be written to the `public/` directory.

You may want to read the [hugo theme documentation](https://gohugo.io/themes/).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I cloned my blog from Github but didn't include themes submodules. Including submodules solved my problem:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/username/your-blog
```

Comment: if you already cloned your repo but not the submodules, use the command `git submodule update --init`

Answer (score 0):

It could be potentially an issue with the `config.toml` in the Hugo project directory.

I recently ran into a similar issue where I was seeing only a blank page while trying to create a custom theme with the Hugo and all you have to do is **tell Hugo where to find your initial HTML page** to render on the browser.

If you are trying to install a theme OR creating a custom theme, go to `config.toml` in the base directory and specify the theme name as given below:

```
theme = "${theme_name}"
```

If you are using the default/custom theme, the theme name will be same as the folder name under **themes** folder in the project directory.